# React Native useState not working on a AsyncStorage fuction

Tags: react-native

**My code is the following:**

```
function ArScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [open_tabLugar, setOpen_tabLugar] = useState(false);
  const [titulo, setTitulo] = useState('');

  const updateAsyncStorage = async () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('data')
        .then((res) => {
        //console.log({ res : JSON.parse(res) });
        console.log(JSON.parse(res).open_tabLugar);
        console.log(JSON.parse(res).titulo);

        setOpen_tabLugar(JSON.parse(res).open_tabLugar);
        setTitulo(JSON.parse(res).titulo);

        console.log(titulo);
        console.log(open_tabLugar);


    }); 
}

useEffect(() => {

    updateAsyncStorage()

    const interval=setInterval(()=>{
      updateAsyncStorage()
     },10000)
     return()=>clearInterval(interval)
     
  }, []);
```

**Output:**

> ```
> console.log(JSON.parse(res).open_tabLugar); ====== true
> console.log(JSON.parse(res).titulo); ===== hello
>
> after setOpen_tabLugar and setTitulo
> console.log(titulo); ===== ""
> console.log(open_tabLugar); ===== false
> ```

Why does that happen? I am changing the state (or trying to change it), but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

If you notice, I have a bucket that updates every 10 seconds in `useEffect`. But, that's not the problem, that works fine (**in the update I retract myself, that is the problem, only I don't know how to solve it**). The problem is in the change of states.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

If I put this:

```
setTitulo("HEEEEEEEEEEEEY");
console.log(titulo);
```

Doesn't work, keeps coming up blank.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I think the problem is inside `useEffect(() => {`
Because I just created a button to run `updateAsyncStorage` manually and it did work.

```
 <TouchableOpacity 
              style={{width: 50, borderRadius: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'white', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}} 
              onPress={() => updateAsyncStorage()} >
              <Text style={{color: 'black', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Load</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

The button does work fine. Yes the state changes. How do I make it work automatically with `useEffect` or another alternative?

---

**UPDATE 3:**

My new code:

```
const [open_tabLugar, setOpen_tabLugar] = useState(false);
const [tabLugar, setTabLugar] = useState(false);


useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('data')
        .then((res) => {
        //console.log({ res : JSON.parse(res) });
        console.log(JSON.parse(res).open_tabLugar);
        console.log(JSON.parse(res).tipo);
        console.log(JSON.parse(res).titulo);
        console.log(JSON.parse(res).descripcion);
        console.log(JSON.parse(res).distance);
        console.log(JSON.parse(res).imagen);
        console.log(JSON.parse(res).imagen_1);

        // string to boolean in AsyncStorage 
        setOpen_tabLugar(JSON.parse(res).open_tabLugar);
        setTipo(JSON.parse(res).tipo);
        setTitulo(JSON.parse(res).titulo);
        setDescripcion(JSON.parse(res).descripcion);
        setDistance(JSON.parse(res).distance);
        setImagen(JSON.parse(res).imagen);
        setImagen_1(JSON.parse(res).imagen_1);

        if(open_tabLugar){
          console.log('-------------- OPEN MODAL --------------');
          setTabLugar(true);
          setOpen_tabLugar(false);
          console.log(open_tabLugar);
        }
    }); 
  },[open_tabLugar, tipo, titulo, descripcion, distance, imagen, imagen_1]);


return(
...

<Modal animationType="slide" transparent={true} visible={tabLugar}>
        <View style={styles_modal.modalViewTabL}>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setTabLugar(!tabLugar)} style={[styles_modal.button, styles_modal.buttonClose]} >
            <Text style={styles_modal.buttonClosetextStyle}>X</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <Text style={styles_modal.place_description} numberOfLines={7}>
            La Casa de la Cultura es una de las más importantes obras de arte de la ciudad de Madrid.
          </Text>

        </View>
</Modal>
```

That works halfway, the problem is that it runs infinitely, it has no end. That started when I put: [open_tabLugar, type, title, description, distance, image, image_1]

After I open my modal with **setTabLugar(true);** I write **setOpen_tabLugar(false);**

That should prevent it from opening it again, but then again it runs as true, infinitely.

---

**UPDATE 4:**

My error is in the following snippet. Since it runs endlessly. If I remove it the loop stops. How do I fix that problem? Remember that I want the modal to open, but not infinitely in a loop.

```
if(open_tabLugar){
      console.log('-------------- OPEN OPEN OPEN TAB LUGAR --------------');
      setTabLugar(true);
      setOpen_tabLugar(false);
      console.log(open_tabLugar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, hooks cannot be used this way. After the set operation is done, the rendering process takes place and the new value you have assigned will then be available. If you have processes that will work according to these values, you should create `useEffect` for this and give the variable you will use to the dependency part.

For example, you can print the current values in the following way.

```
useEffect(() => {
     console.log(titulo);
     console.log(open_tabLugar);       
  },
  [titulo, open_tabLugar],
);
```

You can show it through a real example for better help.

Comment: I honestly don't understand your answer 100%. What should I put in **useEffect** so that the **updateAsyncStorage** function runs infinitely every X time? Some alternative?

Comment: It's still not clear to me, but I put **[title, open_tabPlace]** in the useEffect, but, an endless loop is executed, it does not respect the time of 10000

Comment: See UPDATE 3 of my question please.

Comment: You shouldn't use that state variable where you are performing the assignment. If you really want to print logs, you can do it without changing the state.

In the example you gave, for example, I can't see where the `open_tabLugar` variable is used. If you don't use it, you may not need it.

Comment: Look again, please. I put the modal code snippet.

If you notice, what I try to do is that when **open_tabLugar** is true the modal opens.

Now that works fine, the problem is that it keeps opening infinitely. Even though I set it to false: **setOpen_tabLugar(false);**

Comment: See update 4, please. My error is in: **if(open_tabLugar){...**

Comment: Too many state assignments are used here. After each assignment, the page will render again and because the dependency in useEffect has changed, it will run over and over again and enter an infinite loop. The following change is an alternative solution to avoid looping endlessly.

https://i.ibb.co/YdGK6DW/image.png

Comment: You can also consider assigning the whole incoming object to a state at once.